# Calculate Excel value before import to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, import, calculated-columns

I have problem about import to SQL Server, the scenario is to import excel file and calculate the value in column 3 and 4 (produce column 5) of the imported excel file. In my case, the calculation is in C#, not in excel. And then import to SQL Server (ASP.Net + C#). Any idea how to do this ?

This is my code (it's still give me error)

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (Extension == ".xlsx")
        {
            string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/tampung/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
            //make connection to excel workBook
            using (OleDbConnection oledbcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbcon);

                OleDbDataAdapter ObjAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                oledbcon.Open();
                using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                { 
                    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                    DT.Load(dr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string Year = DT.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                        string StudentName = DT.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                        string Semester = DT.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                        decimal Value1 = Convert.ToDecimal(DT.Rows[i][3]);
                        decimal Value2 = Convert.ToDecimal(DT.Rows[i][4]);
                        decimal AverageValue = Convert.ToDecimal((Value1 + Value2) / 2);
                    }
                    string conString = @"Data Source=PETRELLI;Initial Catalog=demo;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(conString);
                    bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "student";
                    bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
                    oledbcon.Close();
                    Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/temp/")), File.Delete);
                    Label1.Text = "Succeeded";    
                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Hi, it's error";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Please choose the right file excel";
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to know what error do you get

Comment: The error was saying this Sir :
"Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed."

Answer (score 0):

The error should be coming from this line

```
bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
```

This is happening because `DT.Load(dr)`, that you called earlier, have looped through the `dr` already and has moved the pointer to the end, after which you can not use the `dr` again.

```
DT.Load(dr); //<-- this line already looped through the dr. dr can't be used after this line
```

### Solution

Use the `DT` instead of `dr` since you already have `DT` populated with the required data by calling `DT.Load(dr)`

Comment: Thanks @codingbiz, it works great
Anyway, would you like to correct my code because though it succeeded imported to SQL Server but I got my "AverageValue" is NULL in SQL Server
Thanks in advance :-)